# Cannot convert 'System.Collections.Generic.List<long?>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<long>

Tags: c#, linq

Using an `ObservableCollection` with a LINQ query to get an `int` from a SQL Server database table ,I have come across this error. It is suppossed to return a 4 digit integer like this `3125`

> CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<long?>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<long>'

How can this be possible? It is the same type in the `List`.

My code,

```
public static ObservableCollection<long> SearchNameComboStaffNo(DatabaseDataContext database, string staffNameFirst, string staffNameSecond)
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<long>
                   (database.Staff_Data_TBLs
                    .Where(staff => staff.Staff_Name_First == staffNameFirst &&                             
                     staff.Staff_Name_Second == staffNameSecond)
                    .Select(staff => staff.Staff_No).ToList());
        }
```

No matter what I try, I always get a compile error. But, how can it not be able to convert the same type?

Comment: `long?` is not the same type as `long`. A `long?` can be in an invalid state and is thus not directly convertible to `long`.

Comment: @nshct, ahh, I see . So how would this be amended to work? I can't , no matter what I do.

Comment: Either change your return type to `ObservableCollection<long?>` or implement [Grant Winney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38673483/59303)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, `staff.Staff_No` is not a required column in your table, so it's returning a nullable `long` instead of a `long`.

If you want to store it in a list of `long`, modify your query to give it a default value.

```
return new ObservableCollection<long>
       (database.Staff_Data_TBLs
                .Where(staff => staff.Staff_Name_First == staffNameFirst &&                             
                       staff.Staff_Name_Second == staffNameSecond)
                .Select(staff => staff.Staff_No ?? 0).ToList());
```

If it's an `int` in the database and you need to store it in a collection of `long`, you'll need to convert it first, or you'll get an error similar to *"cannot convert from List<int> to List<long?>"*.

```
.Select(staff => (long)staff.Staff_No ?? 0).ToList());
```

Comment: Just curious, the type is an `int` in the database. Do I need to return an `int` or will the long suffice?

Comment: Grant, if I could bother you one last time, why would LINQ be classing `staff_No` as a `long` when it is an `int` in the database? This is just for my understanding.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. Again thanks so much for the help.